# Timer Interrupts (CLNT) and __stack_chk_fail with RISC-V

Tags: linux, assembly, interrupt, riscv, riscv32

I'm writing an emulator and I'm having a bear of a time figuring out exactly what the CPU should do.  I have a system that works, almost all the time.  I can run the NOMMU RV32 Linux kernel if I very carefully pick my CLNT:CPU timer ratio to get really lucky.

I am mimicking what this Stack Overflow answer said as best as I can: [RISC-V Interrupt Handling Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913210/risc-v-interrupt-handling-flow)

And, honestly, it seems to work out well.  I can run user space programs and have my timer run at 250 Hz, **except** sometimes the kernel crashes, and more specifically, it's *almost always* on a `__stack_chk_fail`.  After digging, I still have no idea how the Kernel's handling of interrupts doesn't crash everywhere.  Since, it looks like on an interrupt, the following happens:

- Exchange register `tp` for CSR `CSR_SCRATCH` if zero (happens first time) set them equal.
- Read `sp` `s0` etc... from `tp`'s descriptor.
- Operate on the interrupt.

BUT, `tp` appears to be the same as the currently running (interrupted task). And so it looks like changes to `sp` and more specifically the stack protector aren't understood in the interrupt, so it can overwrite memory that the interrupted task was currently operating in.  In fact, I've stepped through and observed exactly this.

But my kernel seems to boot in QEMU, so I think the issue is with my code.

---

For reference, this is my setup:
My timer ordering is:

- If timer > timer_match AND timermatch != 0 set `mip.mtip` otherwise clear.
- If `mie.mtie == 1` AND `mip.mtip == 1` AND `mstatus.mie == 1` then fire interrupt.

When firing timer interrupt (atomically):

- Set `mstatus.mpie = mstatus.mie`
- Set `mstatus.mie = 0`
- Set `mepc = pc`
- Set `mtval = 0`
- Set `mtcause = 0x80000007`
- Set next PC = `mtvec` (Linux uses all-in-one interrupt handler)

When handling traps, I (atomically):

- Set `mepc = mtval = pc`  << **Note: It seems that this is correct, the spec says so and the kernel advances mepc.**
- Set `mtval = pc`
- Set `mstatus.mpie = mstatus.mie`
- Set `mstatus.mie = 0`
- Set next PC = `mtvec`

When calling `mret` I (atomically):

- Set `mstatus.mie = mstatus.mpie`
- Set `mstatus.mpie = 1`
- Set next PC = `mepc`

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't 100% correct, but this seems to be able to make the system stable.

From pi-maker's rvc, it turns out it is crucial for the kernel to run properly you have to set the `mstatus.mpp` bits, otherwise it will overwrite memory.

The correct solution seems to be here: https://github.com/PiMaker/rvc/blob/master/src/trap.h#L48

But, for testing, I was able to get my project working by the following means.  In addition to the operations described above...

If timer interrupt:

- store last `privilege` into `mstatus.mpp`
- Set new `privilege` to `3`.

If a trap like `ebreak`:

- store last `privilege` into `mstatus.mpp`
- Set new `privilege` to `3`.

If `mret`:

- store last `privilege` into `mstatus.mpp`
- Set new `privilege` to old `mstatus.mpp`

I don't use the `privilege` bits for anything else.  (Note this is probably incorrect, because the selected CSRs should change depending on privilege level, but this seems to work so, ¯\*(ツ)*/¯